# Android URL - Incomplete path

Tags: android, url

I am trying to create a `URL` but it seems that when I create the `URL` it isn't created with the full path.

Creating the URL

```
url = new URL("https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/" + authID + "/Message/");
```

When I get the URL path

```
System.out.println(url.getPath());
```

The result is: `I/System.out: /v1/Account/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Message/`

Does anyone know how can I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just printing out the "path" part of the URL (after the web address)

Try this to show what is happening, I think there is also a toString in url that will allow you to print the entire thing with just url

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com/example");
System.out.println(url.getHost());
System.out.println(url.getPath());
System.out.println(url.getHost() + url.getPath());
```

This outputs

```
google.com
/example
google.com/example
```

Also see the reference

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath()

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Taking just the `url` returns me the full path

```
System.out.println(url);
```